# How to create array to ask user to enter a certain amount of numbers and then take the average

Tags: java

Program asks the user to enter amount of numbers to average

- Creates a new array of the size as amount of numbers (max)
- It stores each number in an array entry
- Prints the numbers entered
- 5 numbers on a line (use print)
- Put a println appropriately (use % check)
- Print the average of all the numbers

This is what i need to do but I don't think I'm starting right as I am new to java
This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AnyAverageArr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the max number:");

    int max = input.nextInt();

    int[] arr1 = new int[max];
    for (int i = 0; 1<= max; i++) {
        arr1[i] = input.nextInt();
    }


    System.out.println("Average of All is " + arr1[max]);

}
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; 1<= max; i++) {` never ends if max > 1. Use `for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this is what you need (explanation comes in comments):

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.print("Please enter the max number:");
    int max = input.nextInt();
    int[] arr1 = new int[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        arr1[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr1[i - 1] + " ");
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        sum += arr1[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Average: " + (sum / max));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Scanner and streams have to be closed. The so-called `try-with-resources` does it for you for free in case of Scanner. Then I read from input, what you did, except the end criteria of my for loop is `i < max`, because `i` will be increased in each loop. `1 <= max` will give you `true` constantly if `max >= 2`.

Comment: Then I print the numbers as you wanted, with `%`. This time `1 <= i <= max`. It's easier to check `%` if I start with 1, but remember: array index starts from 0. Note, that I use the `print` and `println` methods.

Comment: Then comes the good old average calculation. The average of `int`s can be a `double`, so I needed a double variable (e.g. sum) to have a double result of this expression: `sum / max`.

Comment: thanks this is exactly what i needed! I also understood your code which is good I had an idea of this but just conceptually as I wasn't sure how to actually write it on java

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely read about the for loop in java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

You should also read about what average means.
https://www.reference.com/math/average-mean-mathematics-b2fb5e4b69989ed8

Here is a simple quick fix to your code

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the max number:");

        int max = input.nextInt();

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i< max; i++) {
            sum += input.nextInt();
        }


        System.out.println("Average of All is " + sum / max);
```

Comment: OP clearly states _It stores each number in an array entry_.

Comment: small_ticket I understand how to do it with a for loop it is doing it with an array that I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

1. You first need to save all the elements in an array.
2. Then you need to calculate the sum.
3. Divide the sum with the total number of elements.

**Here is a fix for your code:**

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the max number:");

    int numberOfElements = input.nextInt();

    int[] arr = new int[numberOfElements];
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i< numberOfElements; i++) {
        arr[i] = input.nextInt();
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Average of All is " + sum / numberOfElements);
```

**I have used the same loop to save the elements in the array and compute the sum at the same time.**

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

I understood your requirement and i updated little in your source code.
I believe below points you may follow.

1. User enters a max number
2. User want to enter numbers for avarage and that you need to store into an array.
3. Sum array elements and find the avarage of it.

Refer the below source code exactly what you want.

```js
public class StackOverflow {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Please enter the max number:");

      int max = input.nextInt();

      int[] arr1 = new int[max];
      for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
          arr1[i] = input.nextInt();
      }
      
      int sum = 0;
      for(int num : arr1){
       sum = sum + num;
      }
      
      double avg = sum/max;
      
      System.out.println(" Avarage : " + avg);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//here is your edited code
public class AnyAverageArr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the max number:");

    int max = input.nextInt();

    int[] arr1 = new int[max];
    //since array starts from 0, we need to loop less than max
    //i< max : so loop will terminate when we will have input equals to max numbers
    for (int i = 0; i< max; i++) {
        arr1[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    int sum=0;
    //loop again through array and calculate the sum of each number
    for(int v:arr1) {
        sum+=v;
    }
    //divide sum by total number of inputs to get the answer 
    System.out.println("Average of All is " + sum/max);

}
}

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
public class StackOverflow {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      System.out.print("Please enter the max number: ");
      int max = input.nextInt();

      // Creates a new array of the size as amount of numbers (max)
      int[] arr1 = new int[max];
      double sum = 0.0;

      // It stores each number in an array entry
      for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        arr1[i] = input.nextInt();
        sum += arr1[i];
      }

      // Prints the numbers entered
      // 5 numbers on a line (use print)
      // Put a println appropriately (use % check)
      for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr1[i] + " ");
      }

      // Print the average of all the numbers
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Average of all is " + sum / max);
    }
  }

}
```